# WebJarAssetLocator and ClassGraph not compatible in a simple Java project

Tags: java, lombok

When app starts, the following error occurs:

```
/home/anatoly/.jdks/corretto-18.0.2-1/bin/java -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -Dspring.profiles.active=dev,prod -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true -Dmanagement.endpoints.jmx.exposure.include=* -javaagent:/snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/401/lib/idea_rt.jar=40323:/snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/401/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/anatoly/IdeaProjects/LingvoHack/target/classes:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/2.7.4/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.7.4.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/3.0.1/spring-boot-starter-aop-3.0.1.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.19/aspectjweaver-1.9.19.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/3.0.1/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-3.0.1.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/com/zaxxer/HikariCP/5.0.1/HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/6.0.3/spring-jdbc-6.0.3.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/jakarta/transaction/jakarta.transaction-api/2.0.1/jakarta.transaction-api-2.0.1.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/jakarta/persistence/jakarta.persistence-api/3.1.0/jakarta.persistence-api-3.1.0.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.6.11.Final/hibernate-core-5.6.11.Final.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.5.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.5.0.Final.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/net/bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.12.20/byte-buddy-1.12.20.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/2.4.2.Final/jandex-2.4.2.Final.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/5.1.2.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.2.Final.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/4.0.1/jaxb-runtime-4.0.1.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-core/4.0.1/jaxb-core-4.0.1.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/angus/angus-activation/1.0.0/angus-activation-1.0.0.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/txw2/4.0.1/txw2-4.0.1.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/com/sun/istack/istack-commons-runtime/4.1.1/istack-commons-runtime-4.1.1.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/3.0.0/spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/3.0.0/spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/6.0.3/spring-orm-6.0.3.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/6.0.3/spring-context-6.0.3.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/6.0.3/spring-tx-6.0.3.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/6.0.3/spring-beans-6.0.3.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/jakarta/annotation/jakarta.annotation-api/2.1.1/jakarta.annotation-api-2.1.1.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/6.0.3/spring-aspects-6.0.3.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/2.7.4/spring-boot-starter-web-2.7.4.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/3.0.1/spring-boot-starter-3.0.1.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/3.0.1/spring-boot-3.0.1.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/3.0.1/spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.1.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-json/3.0.1/spring-boot-starter-json-3.0.1.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.14.1/jackson-databind-2.14.1.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8/2.14.1/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.14.1.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.14.1/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.14.1.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-parameter-names/2.14.1/jackson-module-parameter-names-2.14.1.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/3.0.1/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-3.0.1.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/10.1.4/tomcat-embed-core-10.1.4.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/10.1.4/tomcat-embed-el-10.1.4.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/10.1.4/tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.4.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/6.0.3/spring-web-6.0.3.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/6.0.3/spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/6.0.3/spring-expression-6.0.3.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/springdoc/springdoc-openapi-ui/1.4.8/springdoc-openapi-ui-1.4.8.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/springdoc/springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core/1.4.8/springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core-1.4.8.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/springdoc/springdoc-openapi-common/1.4.8/springdoc-openapi-common-1.4.8.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/io/swagger/core/v3/swagger-models/2.1.4/swagger-models-2.1.4.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/io/swagger/core/v3/swagger-integration/2.1.4/swagger-integration-2.1.4.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/io/swagger/core/v3/swagger-core/2.1.4/swagger-core-2.1.4.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/jackson-dataformat-yaml/2.14.1/jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.14.1.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/jakarta/validation/jakarta.validation-api/3.0.2/jakarta.validation-api-3.0.2.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/webjars/swagger-ui/3.34.0/swagger-ui-3.34.0.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/webjars/webjars-locator-core/0.52/webjars-locator-core-0.52.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.14.1/jackson-core-2.14.1.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/springdoc/springdoc-openapi-data-rest/1.4.8/springdoc-openapi-data-rest-1.4.8.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/springdoc/springdoc-openapi-hateoas/1.4.8/springdoc-openapi-hateoas-1.4.8.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/springframework/hateoas/spring-hateoas/2.0.0/spring-hateoas-2.0.0.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-rest-core/4.0.0/spring-data-rest-core-4.0.0.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/atteo/evo-inflector/1.3/evo-inflector-1.3.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.14.1/jackson-annotations-2.14.1.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.13/httpclient-4.5.13.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.16/httpcore-4.4.16.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.15/commons-codec-1.15.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/com/jayway/jsonpath/json-path/2.7.0/json-path-2.7.0.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/net/minidev/json-smart/2.4.8/json-smart-2.4.8.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/net/minidev/accessors-smart/2.4.8/accessors-smart-2.4.8.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/9.1/asm-9.1.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/jakarta/xml/bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api/4.0.0/jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.0.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/jakarta/activation/jakarta.activation-api/2.1.0/jakarta.activation-api-2.1.0.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/6.0.3/spring-core-6.0.3.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jcl/6.0.3/spring-jcl-6.0.3.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.18.20/lombok-1.18.20.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/postgresql/postgresql/42.5.0/postgresql-42.5.0.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/checkerframework/checker-qual/3.5.0/checker-qual-3.5.0.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/thingsboard/springfox-swagger2/3.0.4/springfox-swagger2-3.0.4.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/thingsboard/springfox-spi/3.0.4/springfox-spi-3.0.4.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/thingsboard/springfox-core/3.0.4/springfox-core-3.0.4.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/thingsboard/springfox-schema/3.0.4/springfox-schema-3.0.4.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/thingsboard/springfox-swagger-common/3.0.4/springfox-swagger-common-3.0.4.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/io/swagger/core/v3/swagger-annotations/2.1.2/swagger-annotations-2.1.2.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/thingsboard/springfox-spring-web/3.0.4/springfox-spring-web-3.0.4.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/io/github/classgraph/classgraph/4.8.83/classgraph-4.8.83.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/thingsboard/springfox-spring-webmvc/3.0.4/springfox-spring-webmvc-3.0.4.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/thingsboard/springfox-spring-webflux/3.0.4/springfox-spring-webflux-3.0.4.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.5.1/classmate-1.5.1.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/2.0.6/slf4j-api-2.0.6.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/springframework/plugin/spring-plugin-core/2.0.0.RELEASE/spring-plugin-core-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/springframework/plugin/spring-plugin-metadata/2.0.0.RELEASE/spring-plugin-metadata-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/io/swagger/swagger-annotations/1.5.20/swagger-annotations-1.5.20.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/io/swagger/swagger-models/1.5.20/swagger-models-1.5.20.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/mapstruct/mapstruct/1.3.1.Final/mapstruct-1.3.1.Final.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator/3.0.1/spring-boot-starter-actuator-3.0.1.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/3.0.1/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-3.0.1.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-actuator/3.0.1/spring-boot-actuator-3.0.1.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/io/micrometer/micrometer-observation/1.10.2/micrometer-observation-1.10.2.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/io/micrometer/micrometer-commons/1.10.2/micrometer-commons-1.10.2.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/io/micrometer/micrometer-core/1.10.2/micrometer-core-1.10.2.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/hdrhistogram/HdrHistogram/2.1.12/HdrHistogram-2.1.12.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/latencyutils/LatencyUtils/2.0.3/LatencyUtils-2.0.3.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-swagger-ui/2.9.2/springfox-swagger-ui-2.9.2.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.9.2/springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/20.0/guava-20.0.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spi/2.9.2/springfox-spi-2.9.2.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-core/2.9.2/springfox-core-2.9.2.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf/2.7.0/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-2.7.0.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring5/3.0.15.RELEASE/thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/3.1.1.RELEASE/thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/attoparser/attoparser/2.0.6.RELEASE/attoparser-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/unbescape/unbescape/1.1.6.RELEASE/unbescape-1.1.6.RELEASE.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/extras/thymeleaf-extras-java8time/3.0.4.RELEASE/thymeleaf-extras-java8time-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/liquibase/liquibase-core/4.17.2/liquibase-core-4.17.2.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.3.1/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/javax/activation/javax.activation-api/1.2.0/javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.33/snakeyaml-1.33.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/com/opencsv/opencsv/5.7.1/opencsv-5.7.1.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.12.0/commons-lang3-3.12.0.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-text/1.10.0/commons-text-1.10.0.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-collections4/4.4/commons-collections4-4.4.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-log4j2/2.7.3/spring-boot-starter-log4j2-2.7.3.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.19.0/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.19.0.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.19.0/log4j-api-2.19.0.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.19.0/log4j-core-2.19.0.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-jul/2.19.0/log4j-jul-2.19.0.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/2.0.6/jul-to-slf4j-2.0.6.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-security/3.0.1/spring-boot-starter-security-3.0.1.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/6.0.3/spring-aop-6.0.3.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-config/6.0.1/spring-security-config-6.0.1.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/6.0.1/spring-security-core-6.0.1.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-crypto/6.0.1/spring-security-crypto-6.0.1.jar:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/6.0.1/spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar fairytale.DemoApplication
2023-01-04T01:23:05.425+03:00  INFO 9467 --- [           main] f.DemoApplication                        : Starting DemoApplication using Java 18.0.2 with PID 9467 (/home/anatoly/IdeaProjects/LingvoHack/target/classes started by anatoly in /home/anatoly/IdeaProjects/LingvoHack)
2023-01-04T01:23:05.442+03:00  INFO 9467 --- [           main] f.DemoApplication                        : The following 2 profiles are active: "dev", "prod"
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
SLF4J: Class path contains SLF4J bindings targeting slf4j-api versions 1.7.x or earlier.
SLF4J: Ignoring binding found at [jar:file:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.19.0/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.19.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#ignoredBindings for an explanation.
2023-01-04T01:23:06.814+03:00  INFO 9467 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-01-04T01:23:06.844+03:00  INFO 9467 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 20 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-01-04T01:23:07.655+03:00  INFO 9467 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.e.t.TomcatWebServer              : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8888 (http)
2023-01-04T01:23:07.669+03:00  INFO 9467 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.StandardService                  : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-01-04T01:23:07.669+03:00  INFO 9467 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.StandardEngine                   : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.4]
2023-01-04T01:23:07.793+03:00  INFO 9467 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]                        : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-01-04T01:23:07.794+03:00  INFO 9467 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2280 ms
2023-01-04T01:23:08.565+03:00  WARN 9467 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception with message: 'io.github.classgraph.ClassGraph io.github.classgraph.ClassGraph.acceptPaths(java.lang.String[])'
2023-01-04T01:23:08.570+03:00  INFO 9467 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.StandardService                  : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-01-04T01:23:08.606+03:00  INFO 9467 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-01-04T01:23:08.639+03:00 ERROR 9467 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.webjars.WebJarAssetLocator.scanForWebJars(WebJarAssetLocator.java:188)

The following method did not exist:

    'io.github.classgraph.ClassGraph io.github.classgraph.ClassGraph.acceptPaths(java.lang.String[])'

The calling method's class, org.webjars.WebJarAssetLocator, was loaded from the following location:

    jar:file:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/org/webjars/webjars-locator-core/0.52/webjars-locator-core-0.52.jar!/org/webjars/WebJarAssetLocator.class

The called method's class, io.github.classgraph.ClassGraph, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/io/github/classgraph/classgraph/4.8.83/classgraph-4.8.83.jar!/io/github/classgraph/ClassGraph.class

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    io.github.classgraph.ClassGraph: file:/home/anatoly/.m2/repository/io/github/classgraph/classgraph/4.8.83/classgraph-4.8.83.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.webjars.WebJarAssetLocator and io.github.classgraph.ClassGraph


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I throwed out all spring dependencies to firstly try to boot simple app.
Nevertheless, the error came here ))

What can be done?

Answer (score 0):

In case of these strange kinds of mistakes better to create a new pom.xml from start.spring.io
It worked out for me.